# Assigning std::variant from sub-variant

Tags: c++11, variant

Given a `std::variant<A,B,C,...>` is it possible to assign from a aub-type `std::variant<A, B>`?

On MSVC 2019 I get "no suitable user defined conversion" on direct assignment. With std::visit one could implement the folowing:

```
std::variant<A, B, C> x;
std::variant<A, B> y;
std::visit([&x](const auto& value) {
    x = value;
}, y);
```

Is there a more elegant way to implement such an assignment?